# How To Track Down Deserialize XML to Object Error in XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

This is a sample of my xml file:

```
<IFX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="finalizacaoOrcamentoVO">
<dadosOrcamento>...</dadosOrcamento>
<faturamento>...</faturamento>
</IFX>
```

This is my auto-generated by Visual Studio object class:

```
  /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class IFX
{

    private IFXDadosOrcamento dadosOrcamentoField;

    private IFXFaturamento faturamentoField;
```

But I've been getting this error every time I try to deserialize:

**Message "Error document XML (1, 57)." string**

This is my deserialize method:

```
                IFX document;
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file.InputStream))
                {
                    document = (IFX)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
```

Any hint on what should be fixed?
Thanks in advance!

These are my subclasses:
[ClassObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efCM8.jpg)

Comment: 1) You need to do `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IFX));` 2) But there may be another issue -- does `IFX` have a subclass `finalizacaoOrcamentoVO`?

Comment: Validate the xml.  From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Paste xml into view.  Make sure you have only one identification line (1st xml line).  Error will show up in error list like any compiler errors.

Comment: Acctually no, the xml file has no "finalizacaoOrcamentoVO", this is not a subclass of the whole file, I have more subclasses, but none of them are present inside the first tag as this "xsi" thing. I have included in the question a print of all my subclasses, but I guess the real deal is the first line of the xml wich I dunno why it's not being validated for deserialization.

Comment: I just tested, removing manually the "xsi:type="finalizacaoOrcamentoVO"" of the xml and it worked, is there any way I could do this by C# programatically remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xsi:type` attribute, short for `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type`, is a [w3c standard attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) that is used to explicitly assert the type of its element.  As explained in [*Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx), `XmlSerializer` interprets this to mean that the element is serialized from a [polymorphic derived type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) of the expected type.

I.e. if your XML looks like:

> ```
> <IFX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="finalizacaoOrcamentoVO">
>   <dadosOrcamento>
>     <IFXDadosOrcamentoValue>A IFXDadosOrcamentoValue</IFXDadosOrcamentoValue>
>   </dadosOrcamento>
> </IFX>
> ```

Then `XmlSerializer` expects that the following classes will exist:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(finalizacaoOrcamentoVO))]
public partial class IFX
{
    private IFXDadosOrcamento dadosOrcamentoField;

    public IFXDadosOrcamento dadosOrcamento { get { return dadosOrcamentoField; } set { dadosOrcamentoField = value; } }
}

public class finalizacaoOrcamentoVO : IFX
{
    // This derived type may have some or all of the properties shown as elements in the XML file.
}

public class IFXDadosOrcamento
{
    public string IFXDadosOrcamentoValue { get; set; }
}
```

Where `finalizacaoOrcamentoVO` is a type that [inherits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) from `IFX`.

Note the presence of [`[XmlInclude(typeof(finalizacaoOrcamentoVO))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This attribute informs the serializer of the subtypes that might be encountered and *must* be present for every allowed subtype.

Having done this, the XML can now be deserialized via:

```
IFX document;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IFX));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream))
{
    document = (IFX)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

An instance of `finalizacaoOrcamentoVO` will actually get created thereby.

That being said, in your comment you state that your auto-generated classes do not include a derived type `finalizacaoOrcamentoVO`.  If you generated the classes from an XSD, then the XSD and XML do not match and you should get that resolved.  If you generated the classes by pasting this very XML into Visual Studio, then there might be a bug or limitation in Visual Studio's code generation, which can be fixed manually as shown above.

If you really want to ignore the `xsi:type` attribute, then you will have to do so manually, since support for it is built-in to the serializer.  One way is to load into an intermediate `XDocument`:

```
XDocument xDoc;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream))
{
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}

var attr = xDoc.Root.Attribute("{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type");
if (attr != null)
    attr.Remove();

var document = xDoc.Deserialize<IFX>();
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
            return (T)(serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbc!
I acctually don't intend to use the xsi:type attribute, because this is an import from other system, what is relevant for me is only the data inside tags. I choose extension method.
It worked perfectly!